# Using pandas.DataFrame.interpolate to add rows to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following format:

```
    Frequency | Value
1   10          2.8
2   20          2.5
3   30          2.2
4   40          2.3
```

I want to use `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate` in order to add a line at frequency 35 with a value interpolated linearly between frequencies 30 and 40.

In the user manual the example shows how to replace a Nan but not how to add values in between others ([Pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)).

What would be the best way to proceed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need first add new value `35` to `frequency` column by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
df.loc[-1, 'Frequency'] = 35
df = df.sort_values('Frequency').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Frequency  Value
0       10.0    2.8
1       20.0    2.5
2       30.0    2.2
3       35.0    NaN
4       40.0    2.3

df = df.interpolate()
print (df)
   Frequency  Value
0       10.0   2.80
1       20.0   2.50
2       30.0   2.20
3       35.0   2.25
4       40.0   2.30
```

Solution with `Series`, thank you for idea [Rutger Kassies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854578/using-pandas-dataframe-interpolate-to-add-rows-to-dataframe#comment70893217_41854682).

[`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) create `Series` with one column `DataFrame`.

```
s = df.set_index('Frequency').squeeze()
s.loc[35] = np.nan
s = s.sort_index().interpolate(method='index')
print (s)
Frequency
10    2.80
20    2.50
30    2.20
35    2.25
40    2.30
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: If the frequencies are irregular, setting it as the index and using `df.interpolate(method='index')` would take the actual frequency into account.

Comment: @RutgerKassies - yes, I add it to solution.