# Add rows to pandas dataframe using interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, interpolation

I'm trying to do interpolation on a pandas DataFrame that contains time series data. I have hourly data for `temp`, and I want to interpolate the `temp` values at the half-hourly points. This way, I estimate `temp` for every trading period for each day, ie. 24h per day so 48 trading periods per day.

My MWE is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# my dataset
df = pd.DataFrame()
d1 = '2020-10-21'
d2 = '2020-10-22'
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime([d1]*24+[d2]*24, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['time'] = pd.date_range(d1, periods=len(df), freq='H').time
df['temp'] = pd.DataFrame((50+20*np.sin(np.linspace(0,0.91*np.pi,len(df))))).values

# combine time and date
df.loc[:,'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str)+' '+df.time.astype(str))
df = df.drop(['date','time'], axis=1)
df = df.set_index('datetime')

# trading period
df['tp'] = pd.DataFrame(df.index.hour.values*2+1).values

# interpolate to find temp and datetime for trading periods 2,4,6,...
for n in df.tp.values:
    df.loc[-1,'tp'] = n+1
    df = df.sort_values('tp').reset_index(drop=True)

#df = df.interpolate(method='linear')

print(df.head(10))
```

I'm adapting the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854578/using-pandas-dataframe-interpolate-to-add-rows-to-dataframe) post, but I get the error `TypeError: value should be a 'Timestamp' or 'NaT'. Got 'int' instead.` I suspect it's due to the `df.loc[-1,'tp'] = n+1` line but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Reindex such that you have half hour periods. Then call df interpolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.resample('30T').mean().interpolate()
df['tp'] = ((df.index.hour * 60 + df.index.minute) / 30 + 1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks, your method mostly works. I noticed that `tp` goes `45`, `46`, `47`, `24`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ... so I'd prefer if that `24` is `48` instead.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a more general way of doing it though? The `df['tp'] = 1` line implies that the data starts at midnight `00:00:00`, which isn't always the case.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata, can you check my new answer, please? I hope it's right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try `asfreq` and then `interpolate`:

```py
In [36]: df.asfreq('30T').interpolate()
Out[36]:
                          temp    tp
datetime
2020-10-21 00:00:00  50.000000   1.0
2020-10-21 00:30:00  50.607891   2.0
2020-10-21 01:00:00  51.215782   3.0
2020-10-21 01:30:00  51.821424   4.0
2020-10-21 02:00:00  52.427066   5.0
...                        ...   ...
2020-10-22 21:00:00  57.869280  43.0
2020-10-22 21:30:00  57.303145  44.0
2020-10-22 22:00:00  56.737010  45.0
2020-10-22 22:30:00  56.158416  46.0
2020-10-22 23:00:00  55.579822  47.0

[95 rows x 2 columns]
```